# Is there a way to conditional format a dataframe based on a datetime column?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Currently I am cutting my data in what I assume is an inefficient manner. I want to know if it is possible to use conditional formatting via a datetime without creating and dropping a column.

I can solve my problem, but currently I am using

```
input_df['YEAR'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(input_df["TERMSTARTDATE_FORMATTED"]).year
```

then

```
recent_df = input_df.drop(input_df[input_df.YEAR < 2018].index)
```

This works but I can see that it's not elegant. I think there should be a way to just drop the columns from the dataframe without first creating a new column.

Is there a more elegant solution to my problem? What is the pythonic way of dealing with this?

Comment: Use `recent_df = input_df[input_df.YEAR >= 2018]`

Comment: But that still requires me to make a .YEAR column. Whereas I don't want to create that first. I want to use "TERMSTARTDATE_FORMATTED" which is a datetime object

Comment: Yes, then use `recent_df = input_df[input_df["TERMSTARTDATE_FORMATTED"].dt.year >= 2018]`